# Change of values in the traditional Metal Artefact Reduction (MAR) method using radon inverse and filtered back projection

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I'm implementing a traditional interpolation-based metal artefact reduction (MAR) method using the Radon transform and its inverse, which consists of the following steps:

1. The metal body is extracted from the original image.
2. The sinograms are computed both, for the original image and the metal body mask using forward projection.
3. The sinogram of the original image is inpainted along the pixels signalled by the sinogram of the metal body mask, which generates a corrected sinogram.
4. The corrected sinogram is projected back
5. The metal body is restored

As stated in the documentation (https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_radon_transform.html), there is an error in the reconstruction with the Filtered Back Projection (FBP) that is unavoidable. In this example, they use an image with ranges in [0,1] and, after reconstruction, has values in [-0.05, 1.06]. This error does not seem significant but in my case, as I am working with images coming from CBCTs scanners, my range is [-1000, 3095] approximately, and can reach values in [-1000, 360000] in certain cases. Rescaling the image of the example to [-1000, 3095], after applying the inverse transform I get an image with values in [-1340, 3330]. All this can be seen in the following image:
[Test with `shepp_logan_phantom`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7qV3.png)

As an example of a real problem, after applying the MAR in an image with values in [-1000, 3095], the reconstructed image has values in [-1740, 3463]:
[Traditional MAR and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3yWW.png)

The sinogram inpainting is showed in the below image, where the white pixels in the right subplot have a value of zero.
[Sinogram inpainting and difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQl81.png)

The code I use is as follows:

```
thetas = np.linspace(0., 180., num=np.max(image.shape), endpoint=False)
p_orig = radon(image.astype(np.float32), theta=thetas, circle=False)
# here, I apply the inpainting to p_orig
reconstruction_fbp = iradon(p_orig, theta=thetas, circle=False, filter_name="ramp")
```

I am working with `Python v3.8` and `scikit-image==0.19.3`.

This change in values is not always so great. In the image below I show another example where the MAR method works acceptably well (it changes the range of values but in a much smoother way):
[Traditional MAR good and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgMmc.png)
[Sinogram inpainting good and difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lxC.png)

I can handle a change in the range of values but not of such a large magnitude as it would mess up my later tasks. Does anyone know the actual origin of such large errors? Is there any technique that allows me to reduce it? Is this the limit of the method?

Many thanks in advance.